# Append and replace objects in one string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, encoding

I'm writing a text encoder/crypter (all by myself) and i can't understand how to append and replace characters in the string :-/

The code:

```py
import os, sys, random

dig = 0
text_encoded = ""
text = ""

try:
    if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]) == True:
        with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as text:
            text = text.readlines()
except:
    pass

if text == "":
    print("Write the text to encode")
    text = input()

text = text.split()

for _ in range(len(text)):
    text_encoded = text[dig].replace("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm ", "mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq@")
    dig = dig+1

print("Your encoded text is:\n"+text_encoded)
```

Here is some output:

```
Write the text to encode
lo lolo lol lol
Your encoded text is:
lol
```

If you can help me in any way, thank you :-)

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do and provide us with the expected output.

Comment: @AdityaAgrawal I did what you asked :-)

Comment: Please see my answer below, should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting you correctly, you want to replace q with m, w with n and so on. Try the following

```py
import os, sys, random

dig = 0
text_encoded = ""
text = ""

try:
    if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]) == True:
        with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as text:
            text = text.readlines()
except:
    pass

if text == "":
    print("Write the text to encode")
    text = input()

mychars=list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm ")
myencode=list("mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq@")
charmap=zip(mychars,myencode)
_map = dict(charmap)

encoded_text = ''.join(_map.get(c) for c in text)

print("Your encoded text is:\n"+encoded_text)
```

The strings in your question mention that you want to replace ' ' with @. If you do not want to do that, just remove the last characters from both of the above strings.

Comment: It worked but can you explain to me in a really simple way what mychars=list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm ")
myencode=list("mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq@")
charmap=zip(mychars,myencode)
_map = dict(charmap) this do?

Comment: We create two dictionaries, first with the characters you want to be replaced, and second with the characters you want to replace them with. Then we zip them together as tuples and cast them to a dictionary. We then loop over the characters in the text and replace them by getting them from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

have two lists instead of strings like from_ = "abc".split() and to_ = "def".split()
look for your char in from_ and get the index, get the same index char from to_ and stitch it to a new sentence.

```
example:
from_ = "abc".split()
to_ = "def".split()

old_msg = "ab ab"
new_msg = ""
for each in old_msg.split():
    new_msg = new_msg + to_[from_.index(each)]
```

Hope this helps, please add missing char handling and any other edge cases

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `str.translate`

```
import os, sys, random
from pathlib import Path

TEXT_MAP = ("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm ", "mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq@")

def main():
    text = ''
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        fname = sys.argv[1]
        p = Path(fname)
        if p.is_file():
            text = p.read_text().strip()
            print(f'Text from {p} is: {text}')
    if not text:
        text = input("Write the text to encode: ").strip()
    trantab = str.maketrans(*TEXT_MAP)
    text_encoded = text.translate(trantab)
    print("Your encoded text is:\n"+text_encoded)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```